# Navigation View Menu Item Elevations

Tags: android, menu, bottomnavigationview, elevation

I have a bottom navigation bar with 2 menu items inside. I added custom background to both my bottom navigation view (just to have it rounded) and it's items. They work fine but I want to add some elevation to my items as well. How can I achieve this?

My navigation bar code:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/routeCreationNavigationBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:background="@xml/little_rounded_rectangle_bg"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/darkerMainBackgroundColor"
                app:itemRippleColor="@color/rippleColorGrey"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/mainColor"
                app:itemBackground="@xml/creation_mode_radiobutton_bg"
                app:menu="@menu/route_creation_menu" />
```

My menu item background xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="15dp"
                android:height="15dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="7.3dp"
                android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="2"
            android:useLevel="false" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHRH0.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb33A.png)